# How to convert an IOS app that uses an internal URL scheme for updating list items to an Android app that does the same

Tags: java, android

The iOS version of the application is populating menus and listviews from internal URLs which define their content. The goal is to get to the point where the admin can update content and list items from the web and the database will be periodically updated with the changes using REST APIs.

I've read that iOS has more support for internal URL schemes than Android has. I've also read people saying that it is not a good idea to do this in Android.

Comment: Provide examples of what the IOS version of the app is doing with respect to populating menus and listviews.

Comment: IOS and Android are different different plateform. Please check titanium or better to convert it in android Java.